# How to put images for primefaces buttons when mouse over and mouse away from button?

Tags: css, jsf, user-interface, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 3.5

I have a problem while setting images to button when mouse over and mouse away from button.
please tell me how to do it for primefaces.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got it

XHtml Code:

```
    <p:commandButton icon="myIcon" styleClass="myButton"  
                     actionListener="#{routeController.createNewRoute}"
                     update=":routeHeaderForm"/>
```

CSS Code:

```
.myButton .myIcon {
                background: url('../images/add_off_18.png');
                width: 39px; height: 19px;
                left: 1%;
                margin-left:0px;
            }

          .myIcon:hover {
                width: 39px; height: 19px;
                background: url('../images/add_on_18.png');
            }

          .myButton {
                width: 39px; height: 19px;
            }
```