# Primefaces: Button Icon on hover with css

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem with my own css file.
I will change the hover-color of my buttons in css.

```
button:hover * {
    background: #f1f0ef;
}
```

But now the icon of the button is not show on hover effect.

How can i prevent the icon on hover effect?

Comment: Is it possible to post a Demo?

Comment: Here is a Example before/after

![Here is a Example before/after][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pdKYw.png

Comment: Might be this link will be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017725/how-to-put-images-for-primefaces-buttons-when-mouse-over-and-mouse-away-from-but

Comment: I would suggest you to post your answer here. So anyone else if have same problem can get benefited.